# Terms for "half a decade"

Tags: time, archaicisms, measuring-units

Is "lustrum" (pl. lustra) an understandable (say, at least in academic publications) or valid/common term for a five year span, e.g. to use in a table summarizing data where space can be very valuable?  In other words:

- Is "lustrum" archaic?
- Is "pentad" an alternative?

Comment: 'five years' is what one normally uses in English.

Comment: How about *quincade*?

Comment: @Pitarou, decade is from Greek, so it should be pentad, which is also in the OED.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This website](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lustrum) says the last lustrum was held in a.d. 74 by Vespasian. So I would say, no, *lustrum* is not the word you're looking for. *Pentad* is not in some dictionaries, and the one I found that does have it defines it as "a group of five". So that's not the word you're looking for, either. I would suggest

> 5 yr span

if you're trying to squeeze it into as short a space as possible. *Quinquennium* does mean what you want it to, but it's quite rare and fairly long.

Comment: You might as well say that because gladiatorial games were abolished in the 4th century, nobody will understand *gladiator*.  I don't think there's anything wrong with lustrum.

Comment: @Tim: Well, if _Lustrum_ was also the name of a recent Academy Award-winning film, it sure would help.

Comment: I'm going to work "quinquennium" into a conversation soon.

Comment: Diving into ngrams, *lustrum* is apparently not as rare as I’d thought: here, [compare](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=lustrum%2Cquinquennium%2Cfive+year+period%2Cspatula%2Cnarcissus%2Cgladiator&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=0&smoothing=3) it with another somewhat arbitrary selection of words.  However, I share with other answerers the feeling that few English speakers would understand it (especially without a clarifying context).

Comment: *Pentad* has the advantage that people are more likely to be able to guess at least the *five* part of the meaning (by analogy with *pentagon, pentagram* and other words of similar Greek origin). *Lustrum* would leave me guessing.

Comment: The need for this word came up for me recently at work. Pentad may not be technically right but I do like it. As Psmears points out, many people will know "penta" means five. Also "tad" means small. A Pentad is smaller than a decade.

Comment: if you say quinquennium for pentad you must also say decennium for decade

Comment: @Toothrot: But if you say *pentad* for *quinquennium*, then you have to say *milliad* for *millenium*.

Comment: @PeterShor, good point!  but I think you'll find it's _chiliad._

Comment: @PeterShor, I should have checked the OED before I said that.  but _miliad_ is a bastard coinage, which explains its rareness.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is "demi-decade".

Somebody sent me a message saying that people likely needed a citation to a dictionary or the like to validate my response in some unspecified way.  I'm not sure I understand that, as the imminent good sense of the response seems to me to be fairly self-evident.

Nevertheless, if any of you feels the need for additional "authority" from Captain Obvious, please consult the English language dictionary of your choice to see that "demi" means half (as in "demisemiquaver", from the Latin "dimidius", which means to be "cut in half/through the middle"), and "decade" means ten years.

You do the math...

Bart

Comment: Bart, it would be best to not use all caps in a response. I think I would edit the answer. And, you would do well to provide a source, such as a dictionary, to validate your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Pointing out that there are separate dictionary entries for the two components of the word is not the same as showing that the word itself is in general use. As has been observed at [www.macmillandictionary.com/buzzword/entries/demi-decade.html](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/buzzword/entries/demi-decade.html), 'the word *demi-decade*, though perfectly transparent and useful, is yet to be acknowledged by mainstream dictionaries. It's an interesting example of a concept which seems completely obvious, but for which we've been slow to adopt a specific moniker'.